# Keep grep output on one line?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a real quick question for you guys. After looking through the documentation and the site here, I was wondering if it were possible to keep grep from outputting each match on the same line.

In my example, I need to take a string in the format of `\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07...` etc. I use `grep -oP "x\K(\S\S)")` to get each of the hex digit.

The output is correct, however each match is on its own line. This is a problem because I need to feed this output into another program. So again, is there any way to put each match consecutively without any type of padding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could pipe the output to `tr`, e.g.

```
grep -oP "x\K(\S\S)") | tr -d '\n'
```

This costs an additional process, i.e. it makes your program slower. If this is a problem, you can use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Perfect! worked beautifully. I was planning to later use `sed` or `awk` but I've never used them and I am a bit tired to read the docs for those right now.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you feed it to `sed` to remove all newline characters (`\n`)?

```
echo \xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07 | grep -oP "x\K(\S\S)" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'
```

Reference: [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)